# Unable to add data again in Bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am trying to get data from my database on load but on button click when I want to insert data again in the same table I have no clue how to insert it

Here is my HTML code

```
<table id="example" class="display" onload="callData()"></table>
<button type="button" id="idTestTraffic" class="btn btn-primary">Get Test Traffic</button>
```

My JavaScript code

```
function setValue(data) {
    var dataSet = [];
    if (data.response.Status == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.response.Result.length; i++) {

            dataSet.push([])
        }
        for (i = 0; i < data.response.Result.length; i++) {
            dataSet[i].push(i + 1);
            dataSet[i].push(data.response.Result[i].testName);
            dataSet[i].push(data.response.Result[i].view);
            dataSet[i].push(data.response.Result[i].start);
            dataSet[i].push(data.response.Result[i].finish);
        }

    } else
        showMessage("green", data.response.Description, "");

    if (dataSet[0].length == 5)
        return dataSet;
}

function callData() {
    debugger;
    $('#example').DataTable({
        data: dataIsSet(),
        columns: [{
            title: "Sr No."
        }, {
            title: "Test Name"
        }, {
            title: "View"
        }, {
            title: "Start"
        }, {
            title: "Finish"
        }],

    });
}

function dataIsSet() {
    var dataSet = [];
    syncAjaxCall("POST", "trafficanalysis/viewfinishanalysis", "", "application/json")
        .done(
            function(data) {
                dataSet = setValue(data);
            });
    return dataSet;
}
```

On button click my code is

```
$("#idTestTraffic").click(function() {
    syncAjaxCall("POST", "trafficanalysis/viewfinishanalysis", "", "application/json")
        .done(function(data) {
            // I want to set data in same table, but no clue how to set data in same table
            dataSet = setValue(data);
        });

});
```

Comment: You can do it yourself, but it would be definitively easier to search for a jQuery plugin that do that for you or add some other libraries that help for this. Basically you'll have to generate tr node using document.createElement(), then create td node for each value and use the appendCHild to generate the proper view.

Comment: @Walfrat It looks like OP is using Datatables, so they would just need to read the documentation here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add() or here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

You could create a variable / string with the contents of the table and just append it to the `example` id.

Option 2:

Create the elements using `document.createElement()` to create each element, and then append each element into a table row and then finally append to the table `example` itself.

so what I would do:

```
function setValue(data) {
    var html = "";
    if (data.response.Status == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.response.Result.length; i++) {
            html += '<tr>';
            html += '<td>' + (i + 1) + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + data.response.Result[i].testName + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + data.response.Result[i].view + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + data.response.Result[i].start + '</td>';
            html += '<td>' + data.response.Result[i].finish + '</td>';
            html += '</tr>';
        }
    }
    return html;
}
```

And then where you have `dataSet = setValue(data);` just do this:

```
$('#example').append(setValue(data));
```

Comment: well above code works but then search operation does not work on the data set in the table